# What is the net force F for this equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, coulombs-law

I'm new to physics and I have this equation to solve, a detailed answer would be much appreciated!

Two charged particles q1= -5 μc and q2= -4 μc are 50 cm apart on the x-axis. What is the net
force F (magnitude and direction) on a +3 μc charge between them?

[image]

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange is not primarily a homework help site. Homework-like questions should focus on a specific conceptual physics idea.  Please see the homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Note that 5x3x4=60 and 20x30=600.

Comment: What is they all were equally charged (say -5 5 -5) and the red one in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

The first step in solving this problem would be to use F=kQq/r^2 (coulombs law) firstly using q1 and q3 and then repeating using q2 and q3. This would give you the force for both interactions. Since the centre charge is positive whilst the outers are negative the centre is always going to attract to them, therefore whichever has the bigger force the charge will attract to.

E.g. if $k\frac{q_2 q_3}{r^2} > k\frac{q_1 q_3}{r^2}$ then the charge will move towards $q_2$, and if $k\frac{q_2 q_3}{r^2} < k\frac{q_1 q_3}{r^2}$ then the charge will move towards $q_1$, in both cases with a net magnitude of force $|k\frac{q_2q_3}{r^2} - k\frac{q_1q_3}{r^2}|.$

Comment: Please use the MathJax for formulas. See my edits for part of your formulas.